# Integrating lottie-interactivity and Wix (Editor X) for scroll based animation

Tags: javascript, html, lottie, velo

I'm looking to make the lottie animation I have on my Editor X (Wix but with a few more features) site sync with the scroll position.

I found the documentation for [lottie-interactivity](https://docs.lottiefiles.com/lottie-interactivity/configuration-and-usage), but Editor X uses Wix's Velo code for custom elements. Does anyone know how I can apply this scroll animation to my site? I spoke to Wix customer service and they told me that it is possible using custom code.

I've added the Lottie-player and lottie-interactivity packages via npm, but I'm not really sure where to proceed from there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're still looking for how to add them to your site, I've created a Velo Package for Wix that allows you to handle interactivity. So far, it works for Lottie Interactivity's scroll & cursor modes.

Docs - https://doc.clickup.com/2322955/p/h/26wgb-2440/bf1420d753761b2
Demo - https://threedsoftware.com/scroll-alottie

Right now, Wix doesn't allow installation of shared Velo Packages, but I can definitely install it for you to use freely.

**Chris**

Comment: Could you please show me how to manually install this myself?